# Why do built versions of my multiplayer game act different than the version I run in the editor? (Unity / Mirror)

Tags: unity, networking

When loading saved data from a client's PC, it act's different to how my game, running in the editor works. Saved data is only being loaded on the version being played in the editor. Without any specifics, could anyone explain some differences between the editor version of a game and the built version because I was under the impression that they were the exact same.

Comment: Scripts can run in a different order in the built version of the game, which can lead to bugs if a script's Start routine expects another script has already Started and tries to use its data. This can cause exceptions when you try to access data that's still null, aborting execution of your script and stopping important things from happening. To troubleshoot this, we'll need to see the code for the actual thing that's going wrong in your instance. Setting a breakpoint and stepping through it with a debugger can help you identify where the trouble arises.

Comment: @DMGregory It was completely my fault, I didn't understand that there was a seperate debugger for build versions so I was under the impression that certain functions weren't being called while in actuality they were.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, want to document your solution in an Answer below? It might save future devs from running into the same issue.